# Delete a low-quality off-topic question with an up-voted answer

Tags: support, deletion

When I was a relatively new user, I asked a question which I think is low-quality and off-topic (the problem was caused by a simple typo), and apparently other people agree with me since they down-voted the question. Because of this, I would like to delete the question since it is unlikely to help other people. The problem is that I can't delete the question since it has an up-voted answer, which got up-voted probably since it answered my question clearly and explained exactly where the typo was and why it caused problems.

I already voted to close this question, but I would also like to delete it since I don't think it belongs on Stack Overflow and both the question and the answer are unlikely to help other people (although the answer helped me).

Should such a question be deleted? If yes, how do I do it? If not, why not?

Comment: Did you upvote the answer?  If you did, and you retract it, you could then delete the answer.

Comment: @Servy Yes, I up-voted the answer and accepted it since it solved my problem. I can undo that I accepted the answer, but I can't undo the up-vote ("Your vote is now locked unless this answer is edited"). And I don't think that I can delete it since [the Deleting Answers privilege is awarded at 20 000 reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) (and for the moment I only have 1 153).

Comment: You can't delete the answer by itself.  You can delete the question along with the answer so long as there is no answer with a score of 1 or more.

Comment: @Servy I can't undo my up-vote since it was a long time ago I up-voted it and some other people also up-voted it.

Answer (score 9):

You can flag the post and explain to the moderator *why* you feel the post merits deletion, specifically, why the question wouldn't be useful to anyone else.  You should also mention that you cannot delete the question as it has an answer.

Comment: I did as you said and it got declined: "declined - We prefer not to delete questions that folks have taken the time to contribute answers to. If the question can be improved, please edit it to do so." But it can't be improved since the question itself is bad. The only way to improve it would be to change the question.

Comment: @DonaldDuck Apparently you failed to convince the moderator that the question wasn't useful.

Comment: What should I do then? Just leave it there without it being closed or deleted although it's off-topic and not useful? I don't see any other choice, but I dislike leaving a low-quality question there without doing anything about it.